# How to untaint a terraform resource after network issue during application of a terraform plan?

Tags: redis, terraform

I had applied a terraform to create a redis cluster.

Half way through, the application process failed with this error message:

```
Error: Error waiting for elasticache replication group (my-project) to be created: SerializationError: failed decoding Query response
    status code: 200, request id: 3d5a5394-20f0-4834-9e2a-9aff20cceecf
caused by: read tcp 192.168.86.116:53912->54.222.5.156:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

I know that I have successfully created the cluster because I can connect to the redis cluster with `redis-cli`.

However if I do a `terraform apply` again, terraform will say

```
module.my_project.aws_elasticache_replication_group.main[0] is tainted, so must be replaced
```

It is trying to destroy and recreate the resource, instead of the `no action` as I would have expected.

I have tried to import the resource into the state file to rectify the issue. However terraform throws an error:

> Error: Resource already managed by Terraform

If the operation were successful in the first place, I would not see the `tainted` error message.

Is there any way I can recover from this problem? I want to avoid delete and then recreate the resource.

Ideally I hope I can untaint the resource in the state file so terraform will not try to destroy the newly created cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraform marks the object as tainted because, due to the error, it cannot be sure that the object was left in a fully-functional state.

However, if you know (via out-of-band inspection) that the object *was* left in a suitable state, you can override Terraform's determination by using the `terraform untaint` command:

```
terraform untaint module.my_project.aws_elasticache_replication_group.main[0]
```

After this, Terraform will believe that the object is in a suitable state for further actions. Ideally, that will mean that a subsequent `terraform plan` would detect no changes to that instance at all. If the create *was* incomplete but can be repaired through an update, then the provider might produce a plan for an in-place update to match the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I can first remove the resource from the state file, then import again.

**1. Removal**

```
terraform state rm -state=<state-file> "module.my_project.aws_elasticache_replication_group.main[0]"
```

**2. Import**

```
terraform import -state=<state-file> "module.my_project.aws_elasticache_replication_group.main[0]" <resource-id>
```